# windows 2008 server move users to new server

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, migration

I have a new server that is replacing a current windows 2008 server r2. I want to move all the local users and IIS sites to the new box. Is there away to export the two and import them on the new box? I have sync'd all the files for all the sites to the new box. This box doesn't belong to a domain so its not a matter of joining to the domain. The users I'm talking about are the local computer users.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible. Local users are scritable, but not with the passwords (I.e. you can not export the passwords - part of basic computer security).

;) Time to:

- Tink about virtualization and
- think abou the benefits of a domain.

But seriously, you can just export all users and groups with some script in powershell - not that complicated and the powerscipt library has some place to get you started.

http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/yli628/archive/2008/05/13/there-is-always-a-better-way-powershell-export-csv-cmdlet.aspx has a user export script, actually ;)

IIS sites are more tricky - unless you use... WebDeploy (http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy) which can be used to copy IIS settings easily ;)

Answer (score 0):

Windows does have an `addusers` command ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199878 ) that might solve half your problem.  It takes a CSV text file of users and adds them to either the computer or the domain.